# Kendo UI adding new row to grid adds extra row with null value

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I have been trying to figure out what is going on but haven't yet.

Please see the code below.It is a inconsistent behavior, so I am having hard time to catch what triggers it. This grid is inside a popup, I noticed  when i refresh the page and try it, it works fine on first attempt. Then i save/cancel popup and keep repeating it fails at some point and starts accumulate null rows.

I tried to check the value of the grid using

> $('#gridFldListItems').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()

It shows there is no data but as soon as click "Add new Record" it shows 2.

It does not necessarily fail on second attempt, but it never fails on first. I suspect that everytime I open the popup it is not necessarily empty(after first few tries) and it carries some data from previous attempts. I might be wrong.

When I click add new record, it adds a line with null value and gives me an option to input on the second row.

[image]

I also When I put itemname and click update, it does not trigger the "create" event and looks like this:
[image]

At this point the grid broken. Here is the code for the grid

```
var grid = $("#gridFldListItems").kendoGrid({
                editable: {
                    "confirmation": "Are you sure you want to delete this item?",
                    "mode": "inline",
                    "createAt": "bottom"
                },

                selectable: true,
                autoBind: false,
                toolbar: ["create" ],
                columns: [
                    { field: 'Item' },
                    {
                        command: ['edit', 'destroy',
                            { iconClass: "k-icon k-i-arrow-up", click: $.proxy(this, 'selectedFieldDef_onClkMoveUp'), name: 'Up' },
                            { iconClass: "k-icon k-i-arrow-down", click: $.proxy(this, 'selectedFieldDef_onClkMoveDown'), name: 'Down' }], title: '&nbsp;'
                    }
                ],
                dataSource: this.selectedFieldDef_dsItems,

            }).data("kendoGrid");


selectedFieldDef_dsItems: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: function (e) {

                    var field = editViewModel.get("selectedFieldDef");

                    var mapItems = $.map(field.Items, function (item, idx) {
                        return {
                            Item: item
                        };

                    });


                    //on success
                    e.success(mapItems);
                },
                create: function (e) {
                    // on success
                    e.success(e.data);
                },
                update: function (e) {
                    // on success
                    e.success();
                },
                destroy: function (e) {
                    var vm = editViewModel;
                    // locate item in original datasource and remove it
                    var field = vm.get("selectedFieldDef");

                    if (field.DefaultValue && !vm.selectedFieldDef_dsItemsFindItem(vm.selectedFieldDef_dsItems.data(), field.DefaultValue)) {
                        field.DefaultValue = null;
                        vm.set("selectedFieldDef", field);

                        $("#inpFldRegex").kendoDropDownList().data("kendoDropDownList").trigger("change");
                    }

                    // on success
                    e.success();
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("Status: " + e.status + "; Error message: " + e.errorThrown);
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Item",
                    fields: {
                        Item: { editable: true, nullable: true }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
It works fine when I refresh the page

Comment: **"I suspect that everytime I open the popup it is not necessarily empty(after first few tries) and it carries some data from previous attempts"** I agree; I think this is almost certain to be the root of your problem. Can you please share how you open / close / reuse / destroy your window if you haven't solved the problem already?

Comment: It would be helpful to see how / when you call the code which creates your grid as well. Does that happen every time you open the popup window, and if so, are you properly destroying the window (and hence grid) when you close it?

Comment: Joe, we still haven't figured it out yet. We are currently working on "work around" to somehow refresh the page without interrupting user experience. We will come back to it once this version is out and explore deeply

Comment: Ok, so there are two basic approaches to using the kendo window. One is to create it and it's contents once, hold a reference to the window widget and reopen it multiple times. The second approach is to create it and it's contents each time, destroying the window when it is closed. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893016/kendo-window-not-opening-again-once-it-is-destroyed/52893709#52893709) for an example of each approach. I suspect you may be reusing the same window, but possibly recreating the grid each time it is opened, which will definitely cause problems.

Comment: As a quick test perhaps you could try the following to prevent the grid being recreated?

    var grid = $('#gridFldListItems').data("kendoGrid");
    if (grid == null) {
        grid = $("#gridFldListItems").kendoGrid({
            // code to create grid
        }).data("kendoGrid");
    }